# Can't install RedHat 8.4 offline from DVD

Tags: redhat, kickstart

I'm trying to install RedHat 8.4 on a workstation in an isolated network. Is there a way to do it without connecting to the web or a server on the same network ?

The GUI does not seem to provide the option to install from the DVD anymore in this version, and attempting to use a Kickstart file with `repo --name="RpmPackages" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/my_repo` adds a line in the additionnal repositories list but not as a main repository and does not allow the installation to proceed. The 'main' repository appears to have to be a network location as the GUI does not provide the option to use a `file://` path, however this workstation can not connect to anything (first workstation in the isolated network).

Every kickstart example I have found uses an nfs or http server to provide the initial repository.

Is there a way to force an installation from disk or do i have to install a server on a different OS before I can actually start installing the target system ?

Answer (score 1):

### Additionnal details:

The ISO image had been created from the 'boot' image due to disk space and transfer rate considerations and the my_repo folder had been build to contain all required packages.

Usually, when installing from an iso, you should use the `cdrom` command in your kickstart file, which will make use of the `.treeinfo` to find the repositories available on the drive. It is available by default on the DVD ISO but is not on the boot ISO and creating it to index the custom repository seemed to have no effect.

### The answer:

Instead of using a combination of `cdrom` and `repo` commands, simply using `url --url=file:///run/install/repo/my_repo` in the kickstart is sufficient to use the local repository as a main repository. Additionnal repositories may still be provided with the `repo` command if needs be.

**Related documentation**: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user . Section B.2.21 for the specifics of the `url` kickstart command

Note that I'm still interested in being able to generate an iso from a boot iso where `cdrom` already points to the custom repository and will mark as the accepted answer such an answer.